# How to change height of NavigationView top panel

Tags: xaml, uwp

## Problem

I'm using a `NavigationView` in my UWP application with the the `PaneDisplayMode` property set to `Top`. I've added a few menu items, but I'm having trouble adjusting the top pane's height to fit the menu items. At the moment, the pane items are getting cropped.

## What Have I Tried?

I've tried to adjust the `NavigationView`'s `Height` property, but it has no effect on the height of the top bar, only changing the height of the entire `NavigationView` (as one would expect).

## Code

Here is my current XAML code:

```
<NavigationView
        x:Name="navMain"
        IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
        IsSettingsVisible="False"
        IsTabStop="False"
        PaneDisplayMode="Top">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem
                Content="ITEM 1"
                FontSize="60"
                Tag="Page1" />
            <NavigationViewItem
                Content="ITEM2"
                FontSize="60"
                Tag="Page2" />
            <NavigationViewItem
                Content="ITEM 3"
                FontSize="60"
                Tag="Page3" />
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
</NavigationView>
```

## Desired Result

I would like to adjust the top pane's height, **preferably using only XAML**, so that the menu items can fit and not be cropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is due to the default height of NavigationViewTopPane is 40. You set the `FontSize="60"` for the NavigationViewItem is too larger.

To solve this issue, you need to edit the ControlTemplate of NavigationView. An easy way is to follow the [Use tools to work with themes easily](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/control-templates#use-tools-to-work-with-themes-easily) document to edit a copy NavigationView style.

Then, you need to find a Grid named 'TopNavGrid' in the ControlTemplate. The default looks like this `<Grid x:Name="TopNavGrid" Height="{ThemeResource NavigationViewTopPaneHeight}" ...`, you need to change the height to an appropriate value. For example, `<Grid x:Name="TopNavGrid" Height="100" ...`. Then, the menu items will not be cropped.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is override `NavigationViewTopPaneHeight` using lightweight styling, like this (you don't need to re-template the control):

```xml
<muxc:NavigationView.Resources>
  <x:Double x:Key="NavigationViewTopPaneHeight">100</x:Double>
</muxc:NavigationView.Resources>
```