# How can I customize appearance of XAML Navigation View Pane

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a XAML Navigation View control with "Top" PaneDisplayMode.

I would like to increase the pane height and centrally align menu items.

Increasing NavigationViewItem height does not make the pane taller. And changing alignment settings does not affect menu item poistion in the pane.

How can I do this?

```
<Page ... xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" ... >
<Grid>
    <muxc:NavigationView x:Name="NavView"
                         Loaded="NavView_Loaded"
                         ItemInvoked="NavView_ItemInvoked"
                         BackRequested="NavView_BackRequested"
                         PaneDisplayMode="Top">

        <muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Tag="home" Icon="Home" Content="Home"/>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItemSeparator/>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItemHeader x:Name="MainPagesHeader"
                                           Content="Main pages"/>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Tag="apps" Content="Apps">
                <muxc:NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xEB3C;"/>
                </muxc:NavigationViewItem.Icon>
            </muxc:NavigationViewItem>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Tag="games" Content="Games">
                <muxc:NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE7FC;"/>
                </muxc:NavigationViewItem.Icon>
            </muxc:NavigationViewItem>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Tag="music" Icon="Audio" Content="Music"/>
        </muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>

    

        <ScrollViewer>
            <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Padding="12,0,12,24" IsTabStop="True"
                   NavigationFailed="ContentFrame_NavigationFailed"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </muxc:NavigationView>


</Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: You can paste your code first.

Comment: I've added the XAML. The question is really about how to customize appearance of NavigationView control, more specifically the "pane" section. Could not find anything in the documentation.

Comment: I have similar issue and solved it easily as explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55831360/how-to-change-height-of-navigationview-top-panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find the answer so solved it by removing navigation view and implementing something similar myself, sharing here in case someone else is in the same pickle. So this is more of a workaround than an answer. If someone offers a better answer I will accept it.

in NavigationRoot.xaml I have a grid with stack panel for "pane" and frame for pages. Note that buttons have a tag that matches the page tag which I use in navigation (don't judge).

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="Pane" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
        <ToggleButton  x:Name="HomeButton" Content="Home"  Tag="home" Click="Button_Click" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <ToggleButton  x:Name="SettingsButton" Content="Settings" Tag="settings" Click="Button_Click" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Frame Grid.Row="1" x:Name="RootContentFrame"/>
</Grid>
```

In code behind I keep track of "CurrentPageTag" and I have a list of pages.

```
     private string CurrentPageTag;
    
    // List of ValueTuple holding the Navigation Tag and the relative Navigation Page
    private readonly List<(string Tag, Type Page)> _pages = new List<(string Tag, Type Page)>
    {
        ("home", typeof(MainPage)),
        ("settings", typeof(SettingsPage))
    };
```

In the **button_click** event for the toggle buttons I get the button tag and navigate to that page:

```
 string TargetPageTag = (sender as ToggleButton).Tag.ToString();
 //cancel navigation of current and target are the same
 if (TargetPageTag == CurrentPageTag)
 {
     return;
 }
 else
 {
       /*
       you can check that page can be navigated away from here (form 
       validation and the like) and exit early if validation fails. 
       I actually use a global "cancel navigation" variable 
       that pages can set if they are in an incomplete state 
       and should not be navigated away from.
       */
 
   //navigate to target page
   Type targetPage = _pages.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Tag.Equals(targetPageTag)).Page;
   RootContentFrame.Navigate(targetPage);
   CurrentPageTag = targetPageTag;
   return;
 }
```

This gives you basic "navigation view" like functionality with actually heaps less code (but without the ability to change the pane layout on the fly).

What I omitted here for brevity is that I had to style toggle buttons to be more suitable for this purpose. Also, I had them working more like radio buttons where only one is checked at any one time. Perhaps radio buttons should have been used with more styling (but I hate styling so went this route)?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the appearance of the [NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2) by getting the child grid by the [VisualTreeHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper?view=winrt-22621) class.

```
private void NavigationView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

{
// using muxc = Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

```
var navView = sender as muxc.NavigationView;
var rootGrid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(navView, 0) as Grid;
// From the root grid, you can get child elements to customize them.
// You can view the NavigationView diagram from the NavigationView link above.

// Find the top navigation pane and set properties.
var grid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(rootGrid, 1) as Grid;
var topNavArea = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(grid, 0) as StackPanel;
var topNavGrid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(topNavArea, 1) as Grid;

topNavGrid.Height = ...;
topNavGrid.RowDefinitions = ...;
```

}

You have to find your way to the navigation view childs, and you should have a way to customize the navigation view items as above.
You can use the visual tree inspector in Visual studio to inspect the navigation view and to know the child elements.
[See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54999718/how-to-inspect-the-visual-tree-of-any-uwp-app)
I asked Bing AI about inspecting the visual tree for UWP apps, and he gave me that link. Very helpful!
One other way to customize the NavigationView appearance in XAML is to use the Control template and the setter properties.

```
<NavigationView x:Name="NavView">
<NavigationView.Style>
    <Style TargetType="NavigationView" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultNavigationViewStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="NavigationView">
                    <!-- Copy the default template here -->
                    <!-- Find NavigationViewTopPane and change its Height -->
                    <Grid x:Name="NavigationViewTopPane" Height="60">
                        <!-- Other elements -->
                    </Grid>
                    <!-- Find TopNavMenuItemsOverflowHost and change its VerticalAlignment -->
                    <ListView x:Name="TopNavMenuItemsOverflowHost" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <!-- Other elements -->
                    </ListView>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</NavigationView.Style>
```

If you didn't find the "DefaultNavigationViewStyle", you have to add it to the application merged resources. Generics.xaml.